# antd - ant design table with pagination control supporting a widget to choose rows per page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Does the Ant Design Table controller take a Pagination component, instead of a plain object of properties. I need to add a switcher, to switch between rows per page.

Currently it is implemented in the Pagination component.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If what you need is only the ability to select the number of rows per page, then the following code should work for you:

```
<Table
    dataSource={...}
    pagination={{ defaultPageSize: 10, showSizeChanger: true, pageSizeOptions: ['10', '20', '30']}}
>
```

Basically wrapping the [Pagination props](https://ant.design/components/pagination/#API) into a pagination object, and pass it into your Table component.

If you need more customization you might want to consider turning the default Table pagination off and hook up your custom pagination component. Sample code:

[image: Edit nervous-jennings-iw5l6]

Comment: How to hook up my own custom pagination component in antd table, can you give me an example

Comment: Updated the answer with an example codesandbox for the custom pagination component

Answer (score 2):

The above example is a straightforward way to implement the custom pagination. I did, however, notice a small issue with the `getData` function. The table never gets to render the last item in the data array if you use that function. Instead, you might wanna change it to something like

```
const getData = (current, pageSize) => {
return data.slice((current - 1) * pageSize, current * pageSize);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've updated my example.

Comment: The solutions are good but they still have an additional issue, when you have filtering and sorting, the custom Pagination makes your sorting and filtering only work on the current page and not your total data array because the pagination relies on truncating the original full data array, I am thinking of a way around that.